# Why i am getting error zsh event not found on sed command

Tags: sed, escaping

```
sed "s/map(\x27t\x27, \x27<Esc>\x27, \x27<C-\\\\><C-n>\x27)/map(\x27t\x27, \x27<Esc>\x27, \x27<C-\\\\><C-n>:q!<cr>\x27)/g" ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/keymaps.lua

zsh: event not found: <cr>\x27)/g
```

Can you please guide me. What’s the mistake, I am making?

I want to change this

```
map('t', '<Esc>', '<C-\\><C-n>')
```

Into

```
map('t', '<Esc>', '<C-\\><C-n>':q!<cr>)
```

Using Sed

Thanks

Comment: But why not write `'` instead of `\x27`? Note that your question is __not__ how to change the file the way you want, your question is specifically `Why i am getting error zsh event not found`.

Answer (score 1):

`!` is a history expansion in ZSH shell. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html . You are getting the error, because you never had a command that started with `\x27/g`.

Comment: sed is taking ‘t’ comas surrounding as special characters that’s why I am using \x27 to represent. ‘

Comment: I will disagree - no, it's not. For sed `'` is `'`. It may have been you used single quotes, however `sed "s/'/a/"` will replace `'` for `a`.

Comment: sed -i "s/map('t', '<Esc>', '<C-\\><C-n>')/map('t', '<Esc>', '<C-\\><C-n>'):q!<cr>/g" ~/tt.txt
zsh: event not found: <cr>/g

Sorry using command from my phone. But you can see the output. It’s not replacing. And gives error. can you help me to fix the above error.